# Please help me explain how to sort an array without using Array#sort Ruby

Tags: ruby

The bubble_sort method should accept an array of numbers and arrange the elements in increasing order. The method should return the array. I understand the swap part but don't really understand the flipping of true and false and the reason they're there at the first place. It would be great to explain it line by line to help me understand this.

> Do not use the built-in `Array#sort`

```rb
def bubble_sort(arr)
    sorted = false

    while !sorted
        sorted = true
        (0...arr.length-1).each do |i|
            if arr[i] > arr[i+1]
                arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
                sorted = false
            end
        end
    end
    arr

end


p bubble_sort([2, 8, 5, 2, 6])      # => [2, 2, 5, 6, 8]
p bubble_sort([10, 8, 7, 1, 2, 3])  # => [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 10]
```

Comment: Maybe you need an [explainer video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZRWRjq2CAg).

Comment: Try to explain in words when you should stop running the sorting algorithm. If we don't have some kind of stopping condition, then your `while` loop will run forever. So when do we know that a list is sorted?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I don't typically like it when I give someone a hint to a simple question and then someone else answers in detail, so I try to avoid doing it myself. But in this case, I thought about not elaborating on your fine hint, and then it struck me that the reason that the answer isn't obvious to the OP is that he/she doesn't understand how to step through code. So, I "manually" stepped through the code and suggested installing the debugging gems.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we step through the code, using the first example. At the beginning, `sorted` is set to `false`. So the `while` loop kicks in, because `!sorted` is `true`. We start inside the loop by setting `sorted` back to true. Then we use `#each` to go through the array elements. We compare each element to the element following it. If the first element is greater than the next one, we flip them and set `sorted` to false.

If `sorted` is `false`, we repeat the `while` loop, again setting `sorted` to `true` and using `#each` to run through the array. If we go through the entire array without having to flip any elements, then `sorted` never gets set to `false`, we exit the loop, and the array is sorted.

In the first example, `[2, 8, 5, 2, 6]`, it looks like this. First pass: `2` and `8` are left as is. `8` and `5` get flipped (and `sorted` gets set to `false`). `8` and `2` get flipped. `8` and `6` get flipped. Array now looks like `[2, 5, 2, 6, 8]`.

Next pass: `2` and `5` are left as is. `5` and `2` get flipped (and `sorted` gets set to `false`). `5` and `6` are left as is. `6` and `8` are left as is. Array now looks like `[2, 2, 5, 6, 8]`.

Next pass: array is in sorted order, nothing gets flipped, `sorted` doesn't get changed to `false`, we exit the loop and return the sorted array.

If you want to get a better idea of how it works, you can add the line `p arr` just before the end of the `while` loop. Then it will print out the changes that each pass through the loop makes.

I would also recommend that you install and learn how to use [pry and pry-byebug](https://rubygems.org/gems/pry-byebug/versions/3.4.0). If you were able to step through this code, I think you would see how it works very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason **why** you swapped something is that you knew by the time that the array is not sorted yet. In an already sorted array, you would never swap anything. `sorted = false` just records this fact.